# Retrieving In App Purchase products that has not been submitted yet?

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am currently developing an IOS App (XCode 8 beta w/ Swift 3) that pulls IAP products. I am running things on the simulator currently.

I am following this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial

**Issue**

When i request for products i am not retrieving anything. I am 1 IAP product on iTunesConnect that is in "Ready to submit" state.

**Question**

Is it possible to retrieve IAP products that are in "Ready to submit" state?
If not, how to test IAP purchases BEFORE submitting (or having the app/iap approved)?

Comment: You need to submit them to test your IAP products. Even if your app is live you can submit your products and test them but they will not appear in your app till you don't add their product identifiers when you initialise your SKProductsRequest.

Comment: So once i submit i can begin retrieving the products? Or do you mean i have to submit AND have the app approved?

Comment: When you submit the IAP products in itunes connect and they are approved you can start to test them. They will never appear in your live app till you don't add them (in your code) as SKProductsRequest. So don't worry if they are approved, the user will not see them.

Comment: Ah ha. I am just now learning that the IAP product identifiers must either be hard-coded or retrieved via some external mechanism (no internal API to do this?). Now this is making sense. I am going to get my app submitted now so i can start testing the IAP's. Thanks all.

Comment: Nice to help you. It would be nice if you mark my answer as the correct answer for your question. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is NO, you can't retrieve your IAP unless you submit them for review and they get approved.

Also, please note that submitting new IAP for your next app version that is still in development will not have any effect on your current one, and users won't even discover that.

This is the same as if you used to have an IAP then remove it from sale, then it won't be available for users.

Also, think about managing your IAP availability using a web service in your website or a downloadable configuration data. This would allow you, for example, to add or disable occasional promotional IAP for your app WITHOUT having to update the app itself.

Finally, be sure that all your IAP are submitted before you submit your app's binary for review. I once had an app rejected because one of the IAP was not working, due to rejected description (too short).

Good luck

Comment: Why submit all IAP's before app binary? If apple accepts the binary, then any subsequent IAP reviews will be much easier, right? Because a failed IAP review should not affect the already approved binary,right?

Comment: Also, when you say manage IAP available via a web service or site, do you essentially mean maintaining a list of the product identifier strings?

Comment: If you want your IAP to be included in the accepted binary, you should submit them and get them approved before Apple team tests the app itself. Also, be sure that they test all IAP using the binary. If they find that an IAP button is not working (for example because you did not submit it), the binary will be rejected.

Answer (score 5):

As of June 2018 I don't believe the other answers are correct. Certainly not for apps that already have one IAP approved.

I have an app on the App Store with several IAPs (non-consumables, and an auto-renewing subscription) approved and live. 
I'm now trying to add another auto-renewing subscription.

I created my new auto-renewing sub, and it is currently in the state *Ready to Submit*. It is not approved. When I request it via `SKProductsRequest`, it **is** in the results. Note that i'm running in a debug build configuration which is I'm guessing is necessary for this unapproved IAP to show up.

So my answer is: yes, **you can retrieve IAPs that have not been submitted yet.**

Answer (score 1):

I was working on IAP and came across this question, I am answering it for those who will be implementing this now and after. I don't know about eariler but now you can test IAP products that are in "Ready to submit" state. I have followed the same tutorial and its working without submitting product for review for sandbox testing environment. You only need to submit your products for review for them to work live on appStore.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented you need to submit your IAP products to be able to test them.

You need to submit them to test your IAP products. Even if your app is live you can submit your products and test them but they will not appear in your app till you don't add their product identifiers when you initialise your SKProductsRequest.

Don't forget to create a sandbox user to login in App Store with that user to test your IAP products. You should see [Environment: sandbox] in the alert to confirm your buy.