# react-native-iap getProducts() returns undefined on EAS built iOS app

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase, eas, react-native-iap

I'm working on an iOS app built with Expo Application Services (EAS) and encountering issues with the react-native-iap library:

- `getProducts({skus: ['Credits30']})` unexpectedly returns undefined.
- `requestPurchase({ sku: 'Credits30' })` results in an error: "Invalid product ID".

Despite researching extensively and following documentation and related SO questions (links provided), the issue persists:

1. [Fluffys Zero IAP Products Checklist](https://fluffy.es/zero-iap-products-checklist/)
2. [React Native IAP Troubleshooting](https://react-native-iap.dooboolab.com/docs/guides/troubleshooting/)
3. [SO - Retrieving In App Purchase products that has not been submitted yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157783/retrieving-in-app-purchase-products-that-has-not-been-submitted-yet)

Here's a detailed checklist of what I've verified:

**Tax and Banking:**

- Active paid Apple developer account.
- Active agreements for free and paid apps.
- Tax and Banking info provided in App Store Connect.

**App setup:**

- App created in App Store Connect with matching App ID.
- Matching bundle ID in EAS build and App Store Connect.
- Enabled in-app purchases in the app's provisioning profile.
- In-app purchase items in App Store Connect set to 'Ready to Submit'.

**Client-side:**

- Using correct product IDs.
- Waited several days after creating in-app purchase items.
- As suggested [here](https://github.com/dooboolab-community/react-native-iap/issues/723#issuecomment-817375164), I've tried calling initConnection before calling getProducts/requestPurchase. initConnection returns 'true'.
- Same issue occurs in both Simulator and on physical device with development build.

I have a few questions that may help ellucidate the issue:

1. Can I fetch products if the app's status is 'Prepare for Submission', or does it need to be under review or launched?
2. Do I need to add any specific configuration in app.config.js for IAP?
3. Is there any eas.json configuration I might be missing?
4. Regarding Sandbox testing: is it necessary for product fetching, and if so, how can I add a Sandbox tester in an EAS built app since the option doesn't appear in Settings > App Store?

I'm using React Native ["0.72.4"], react-native-iap ["^12.10.7"], and Expo ["^49.0.10"].

Would really appreciate any help or insight as I've been trying to pinpoint the issue for several days now!